# How to get multi-line parameters in c#

Tags: c#, parameters, console, console-application

Is there any way to get multiple lines of parameters parsed through the main entry point in a c# application? Suppose I have this batch process:

```
myapp.exe (
param1
param2
param3
)
```

How would I get these parameters inside the console application?

myapp.exe:

```
using System;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
                               // ^ Get parameters here
        {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get parameters like this :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string param1 = args[0];
    string param2 = args[1];
    string param3 = args[2];
}
```

and launch the application like :

```
myapp.exe param1 param2 param3
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you are looking for something like this:

```
  public void Some(params int[] values)
    {
    //some code
    }
```

Than you can call this method as follow:

```
Some(1,2,3,4,5) //as many numbers as you need
```